# Turn device off instead of rebooting as device owner

Tags: android, device-owner

With the Android device owner API it is possible to reboot the device (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#reboot(android.content.ComponentName)) which to me is permission wise pretty much the same as shutting the device down.

Still I can't find any mentioning of the possibility to shut down a device programmatically as a device owner. Is that today in any way possible without root?

There are a few old questions discussing this but since then quite a lot has changed in Android, rebooting without root f.e. was not possible back then so I was hoping a full shut down might be possible now as well.